# Tomcat startup script not running

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

So I've followed the list of steps on : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04.

When I try to run the startup script `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`, I get this message:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
>   Using CLASSPATH:
>   /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   touch: cannot touch `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
>   /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 389: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create   /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out:

What am I supposed to do to get that startup script to work?

Comment: try sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

Comment: I get `:/var$ sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh  
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7  
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7  
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp  
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar  
touch: cannot touch` `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory  
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 389:   /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create   /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent`

Comment: do you install tomcat using apt-get?

Comment: @study, yes I did `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`

Comment: try sudo service tomcat start

Comment: @study I tried that, I then type `ps -ef | grep java | grep 8080` and nothing comes up.

Answer (score 3):

Try to:

```
mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/; chown user_running_tomcat /usr/share/tomcat7/logs
```

Comment: Would I have to make folders, I'd assume they'd be created when I install, that's how it was on Windows for me.

Comment: For me I just remade the logs directory and gave the entire directory back over to tomcat. This was on a goofing around enviroment not something thats going to stay for more than one day so I really didnt care what I messed up and just wanted to get tomcat back up real quick ;) `chown tomcat:tomcat -R tomcat8`

Answer (score 3):

You installed Tomcat as the root user (which is the default installation via apt-get), and so some of its directories are under ownership of root. Which means you would have to call the startup script using `sudo ./startup.sh`.

I don't recommend the apt-get installation of tomcat at all, because it installs files all over your system and it can get rather confusing. I recommend downloading Tomcat directly from the Apache site instead.